# How tranlsate a specific file (like index.php) with Poedit?

Tags: php, poedit

I have a problem....I work in a project (that is too big so i cant download all on my file) and i asked me if i could grab and drop my file index.php into Poedit and translate (with the others translations that I have in the other little project tha i could downloaded in my PC in .po file). I ask if there is another solution and not downlad all file of the server.

Just in case I repeat...I have worked with Poedit...I downloaded the little project on my PC and in Catalog's Properties I used the address file and that was to easy...but here the project is too big and it is via FTP only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Poedit (latest version, i.e. 1.8.8 at the moment, because old(er) versions indeed couldn't do this), go to *Catalog→Properties→Source paths* and simply add the file you want to scan, instead of a folder. Couldn't be simpler.

Comment: Yes i did it but all old translated words dispaear. When i put in source path home/project/index.php poedit do the same that you said but when I put update the translated words of the little project dispear.( I use 1.5.4) i think is the lastest in linux....in 1.8.8 it happens?

Comment: Nothing “disappears” if you set things (paths & keywords) correctly. And when I specifically refer to 1.8.8, yes, I actually do mean 1.8.8 and not some *ancient* version like 1.5.4...

Comment: ok i will wait for poedit 1.8.8 in linux because i download it in the webpage and the folder say poedit 1.8.8 but when i install that I go to help and says 1.5.4.

Comment: I tried the new version in a Windows and it works how you said.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. You can ask them if they can put all the strings in a single file. This is the typical approach followed in some PHP frameworks. All language strings are stored in a single file, one file for each language. So if they can provide you such a file, that will help.
2. If that is too much work for them to do, ask them to create a zip file of their entire project so you have to download only the zip file & then unzip it on your local.

I hope that helps. If you were looking for something else, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks but..1- It's good idea but this is not what I want.2- I cant download al the files in a zip...beacuase is too big. Thanks for asnwer my question I appreciate this.